# Swift - turning EPS file (or similar) to Core Graphics path

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-graphics

I want to mask a `UIView` with a Core Graphics path. I’ve created this path in the Grapher tool on OS X and saved it as a vector file (specifically EPS file) hoping to load it in to iOS and mask the `UIView`. This way I don’t have to use a bitmap image.

I can’t seem to find a way to turn a vector image in to a Core Graphics path though, if anyone has any idea I’d love to know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: Since XCode6 it is possible to add **Vector** images, skipping the part of preparing 1,2,3x versions. Saves time and looks perfect. **The format is PDF**, which you may export in correct size from apps like Sketch or Graphic (formerly iDraw) and others.
Full tutorial featured here: http://www.appcoda.com/xcode6-tips-tricks/ 
Scroll way down for Vector tutorial almost to end of an article.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to use EPS for vector graphics in iOs and honestly there's a better way to do this, as there are apps for that. The process is much more similar to SVG not EPS images. What you need is an app, that can export Core Graphics code.

I am using iDraw, that can both export graphics as CSS code for web site design and Core Graphics code for iOs app design. Sketch app for Mac does this as well. Both of these are cheap compared to Big Name vector graphics software.

So here is a workflow. You import EPS or draw a custom illustration, group shapes, right click on it and copy as a core graphics code. Then paste it in let's say a Cocoa Touch class Swift file, draw it (get the Graphics Context -> draw shapes at coordinates -> add subview to view).

```
// get the graphics context
var context = UIGraphicsCurrentContext()

// draw shapes here or paste core graphics code
// don't forget about coordinates (theyr'e not the same as pasted from graphics software)

// Add to view
var yourView = ShapeViewName(frame: CGRectMake ( .... ))
view.addSubView(yourView)
```

Hope this helps.